# Admin login doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login

When I wanted to login in my localhost xampp server with magento I got a problem. The problem is that magento when I enter my user account gives me a key but he didn't redirect me to my admin home page. I have changed my password with mysql but it still doesn't work. I neither got an error that means that the username and password are correct. But it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to login with another browser
Or clear your browser cookies,
cache and such.
I always swap browsers : Firefox to Chrome.

Too attached to my cookies :)